# Is there a way to parse JSON so I don't lose numerical precision?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm currently using Google Apps Script's built in JSON parser and running into an issue for large numbers (say 692996696181207**8593**) where parser truncates the precision down (to say 692996696181207**9000**). Is there another parser that can be used to maintain the precision? Or is it best to re-write a parser to accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it) / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

This is a JavaScript limitation because it uses floating point numbers. So the biggest integer you can have is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` which have value 2<sup>53</sup> - 1 or 9007199254740991. If the number is bigger, you will start loosing precision ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER#description)). To have bigger integers than that, you have `BigInt` ([see reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)). `JSON.parse` uses the regular numbers, so you'll have to use one of the libraries capable to parse JSON with `BigInt` (or implement it yourself, but I would advice against it).

### References

- [BigInt (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)
- [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)